# Show any arbitrary interval has a zero in it

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and whenever $f(a)=f(b)=0$ for some $0\le a,b\le 1$, there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0.$ Show that for all arbitrary open intervals $(y,z)\subseteq(0,1),$  we have $(y,z)$ contains a zero of $f$. Does anyone have any hints

Comment: .... let $y=0$ and $z=1$?

Comment: Do you mean to say instead that **for all** *arbitrary open intervals* $(y,z)$ we have that it contains a zero of $f$ rather than **there exists** an open interval such that it contains a zero of $f$?  These are very different problems.

Comment: suppose there is an interval $(y,z)$ so that f is non zero in the whole interval, continuity of $f$ will produce an interval $[a,b]$ which contains $(y,z)$, with $f(a)=f(b)=0$, but there is no zero in $(a,b)$

Comment: @user604175 as JMoravitz points out in your question you say show that we can find some arbitrary  open interval well then we can just use the interval given in the question that is $(0,1)$ since it was stated to contain a 0 however by wanting the condition for any arbitrary interval that is a subset of (0,1) the question is different.

Comment: @Thehomeschooler, yes thank you, I am aware and have changed the question

Comment: @JMoravitz yes I do sorry and I changed the question

Answer (score 1):

Start with the two given zeroes of $f$, $0$ and $1$. Then you get $c \in (0,1)$, a zero of $f$. Now, if $c \notin (x,y)$, $(x,y)$ must be contained in either $(0,c)$ or $(c,1)$ (why?). WLOG, let it be inside $(0,c)$, now we find $d \in (0,c)$, another zero of $f$ and continue like this. Why can this not contninue forever? (Hint: Look at the length of $(x,y)$ and the lengths of the constructed intervals in each stage).